# select dates between ranges in r

Tags: r, date

In dataset, I have date variable that has this format : "2020-01-01"
This variable is stored as "Date" format

This code works:

```
dataset[which(dataset$date_variable > 2020-01-01),]
```

This code also works:

```
 dataset[which(dataset$date_variable > 2020-01-19),]
```

But together I get no output:

```
dataset[which(dataset$date_variable > 2020-01-01 & dataset$date_variable < 2020-01-19),]
# produce empty result
```

How I can correct this code? How in R to subset between date range? I should maybe convert variable type format?

Comment: Paste the output of `dput(head(dataset,10))` into your question.

Comment: In the second example that "also" works you're using greather than ">" while in that that doesn't you're using less-than "<"

Comment: dput result: dput(head(dataset$date_variable))

Comment: structure(c(17555, 17555, 17554), class = "Date"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2018-01-25 means 2018 minus 1 minus 25.  Surround the dates with quotes since Date objects can be compared to character representations. Using the reproducible input in the Note at the end we have the following.

```
x[x > "2018-01-24" & x < "2018-01-26"]
## [1] "2018-01-25"
```

### Note

```
x <- structure(c(17556, 17555, 17554), class = "Date")
x
## [1] "2018-01-25" "2018-01-24" "2018-01-23"
```

Comment: it works but I would suggest to use `x[x > as.Date("2018-01-24") & x < as.Date("2018-01-26")]` and not depend on the fact that the result is the same. What happens is that we compare two strings, where the precedence is luckily not interfering with the results. It is a good habbit to compare Dates with Dates, same as numbers with numbers. Realize for example that `200 < "3"` is `TRUE`

Comment: @Merijn van Tilborg, Date comparison operators already coerce their arguments to Date.  No need to do it yourself.  This code is in Ops.Date: `if (is.character(e2)) 
e2 <- as.Date(e2)` where e2 is the second argument.

Comment: ah I see, fair point and I did not know that. I think it is still a good habit though to compare between same types of data. Unless you want to remember it works like that for dates, while `200 < "3"` it is not the second part after the operator beging coerced but the first part considered a string and not the second part being coerced to numeric. But you are 100% correct with dates it is not needed at all.